# Is it possible to have a ListView in a Fragment - or a ListFragment in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android

In my application I want a panel that contains some text information then below it a list of menu items. What is the best way to do this?

Is it possible to have a ListView within the fragment along with other TextView's etc.

If not is it possible to have a ListFragment within a Fragment? That is what I am attempting at the moment but when I try and run it I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment LeftMenuFragment{4089c090} not attached to Activity
```

Comment: need to see the code.. oncreate and xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have listview in a fragment. Like ListActivty there is Listfragment which you can use for using ListView in your application.

See this market [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) for help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'Yes' we can have a listview  in fragment. The error is self explanatory. You hav not added it to the activity or any layout.

Comment: if you add a listview in the xml for the fragment how do you initialise it in the fragment class?

Comment: need to see onCreateView of your fragment class.